# asp.net VB best way to return result code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

For asp.net framework 4.5  vb

I know that I can use a session variable.. but wondering if there is a more efficient way to return a variable (we call it a condition code) that we set almost in every function /sub being called.

Example

```
  Function xyz(bla as String, blab as String) as dataset
    .. do the deed
    **Cond.code = -1**  

  Return ds
```

We use this Cond.code everywhere.  Obviously it can not be a Public Shared variable... but want the most efficient way to always set a "condtion  code" within any sub or function...   It is valid, only from the time it is set, to the time it is checked by the calling function... so the lifetime is very short.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what, exactly the condition code is used for.  It's possible that a proper use of custom exception types would replace the need for it.  However, if you really need it, it would be better to have it be returned by the method, rather than essentially setting a global, which is pretty rotten.  What happens if two methods ever got called simultaneously?  It's just brittle and unnecessarily confining.

For instance, you could make a container to hold the return value *plus* the condition code, like this:

```
Public Class ReturnValue(Of T)
    Public Sub New(value As T, conditionCode As Integer)
        Me.Value = value
        Me.ConditionCode = conditionCode 
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Value As T
    Public ReadOnly ConditionCode As Integer
End Class
```

By requiring the code in the constructor, like that, it forces every method to always specify a condition code in its return value.  That way it could never be forgotten:

```
Function xyz(bla As String, blab As String) As ReturnValue(Of DataSet)
    ' do the deed
    Return New ReturnValue(ds, -1)
End Function
```

However, even then, I would still strongly recommend making the condition code use an enumeration or, at the very least, a set of constants.  `-1` isn't very self documenting.